# Change application name on Android home screen

Tags: android

Is it possible to change dynamically (for example defined by user) the application's name shows in Android home screen?

I would like to give a name to application on Android Market, but show another name, defined by user, in Android home screen.

Answer (score 0):

The value that shows in the Play Market comes from your AndroidManifest.xml.

You can externalize it to a value in your Strings.xml file - but I don't think there is a way to change those values during runtime.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint you, but it isn't possible at all. It's a fixed string in AndroidManifest file.